# Convert multiple Bézier segments to a nurbs curve

Tags: curves, spline, bezier-curve

I have multiple cubic Bézier curve segments which are contiguous and G1 (they are the result of the fitting of many curve samples).

Now I would like to transform these Bézier segments into a single NURBS curve. When there is a single Bézier segment, the operation is rather easy:

- Same 4 control points as the Bézier segment
- Knots vector is 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
- degree is 3

Now when there are multiple Bézier segments I don't know what to do to convert them into a single NURBS. Any idea?

Comment: You ain't got a NURationalBS unless you choose weights for each control point. If you really want a NURBS and not just a b-spline, all weights must, however, be identical and positive even when multiple Bézier segments are joined.

Comment: @Coolwater: my bézier curve is already rational, so nothing special to do here as I already work in homogeneous space.

Comment: Are your rational Bezier curves G1 in homogeous space or in the Euclidean space?